# C Link Library Independant to Build

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries, cross-compiling

I want do develop a executable in C and share this executable, that it can run on other target Systems. The devepoment system is Linux 64Bit and the target system is a Linux ARM system. I developed it because of laziness using shared libraries but if i share it, for sure it wont work, because the shared objects are missing. I tried to Change from shared to static libraries by building up the library from source, because it didn't offer static libraries, but when i try to build the Project, it gives undefined reference error. This should be related to the missing Header files. But if i include the Header files in the build process, there is the same Problem when i distribute them.

Is there a posibility to use libraries but build a independant executable, where i don't have to install or copy other stuff but the executable to to target System?

Cross-compiling works fine, just the library makes Problems.

Comment: Did you consider sharing the C source code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using functions from within libraries, you have the option of either using the dynamic library (and require it to be installed, or install yourself)

or use static libraries which will get combined with your program (if you can build static libs)

Most often issues with trying to build with static libs, is that you may also need to static link with any other libs that that library also depends on.

Answer (score 1):

When talking cross comparability, you want to *avoid* static linking. Because those libraries could already be built and debugged on ARM systems. You simply install the already working shared libraries for that architecture on to the system, and then your program will work fine.

You also face the problem that those shared libraries, are dependent on *other* shared libraries. Those too you would also have to rebuild. So by the end of the day you'll have a 3GB executable.

I recommended you do some practice with packaging (oh no he said it). Create a .deb or .rpm that will install the dependent libraries for you.